# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SecureRandom(provider: IBMJCE)cannot be found

Tags: java, server, jar, weblogic12c

This error occur when the use **SecureRandom()** inside of application. **ibmjceprovider.jar** is build with project and it deployed successfully. (ibmjceprovider.jar already in WEB-INF/lib)

> the oracle **weblogic** server not loading the **ibmjceprovider.jar**

java version 1.6

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SecureRandom(provider: IBMJCE)cannot be found.
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:206)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:155)
```

As i think web logic server not use my project /libs

How i handle this in project environment

Answer (score 0):

this issue resolve after restarting web-logic server.